# H2 jdbc exception - Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2, flyway

The following stmt works on mysql but not on H2 Database

insert into XXX(content)
  select 
         convert('{
                                  "text" : "testsee",
                                  "url" : "http://hjh.com",
                                  "phone" : ""
                                }', BINARY) as content
  from ...

SQL State  : 90003
Error Code : 90003
Message    : Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "{
                                  ""text"" : ""testsee"",
                                  ""url"" : ""http://hjh.com"",
                                  ""phone"" : """"
                                }"; SQL statement:
Can anyone tell me how can i fix this issue?
content column is of type blob. 
This is a spring boot microservice where tests run on H2.
The stmt is written in puresql, and executed by flyway during start up.

Answer (score 2):

This occours because the database is trying to convert a Java String to a BLOB (byte string), change the type of the column to defined as BLOB to VARCHAR(size) or TEXT.

You can also check this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html

> A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. The four BLOB types are TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold. The four TEXT types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT. These correspond to the four BLOB types and have the same maximum lengths and storage requirements.

Comment: I cannot change the column type to Varchar.. it contains data upto 1MB.  These are pure sql scripts:  update etui_template SET content =
               (select convert('{"text" : "testsee",
                                  "url" : "",
                                  "phone" : "",
                                  "driverDistraction" : false,
                                  "expirationDate" : 0,
                                  "freeTextApplication" : 1}', BINARY) as c

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check if it can help you.

Comment: Actually cannot change the column type.. i need to find a way thhat the same sql script gets executed on MYSQL and H2 database

Comment: So, you cannot save a character strings within a blob. Blob`s are designed for byte strings. A not elegant way to solve you problem would be convert you strings to hex before save in database.

Comment: Actually I am converting to bytes using :  select convert('{ "text" : "testsee", "url" : "http://hjh.com", "phone" : "" }', BINARY) as content

Answer (score 0):

I found in [this source](https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/fiUw3tqRb1o?pli=1), a way to insert hex data into H2 database. But first it's necessary use [some online tool](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php) to convert text to hex and then use a insert like this one

```sql
-- data = 'Text to me inserted'
insert into TABLE (blob_column) values ( X'5465787420746f206d6520696e736572746564' )
```